# C++ arrays and stuff

Tags: c++, arrays

I must prefix, this is probably a softball question for someone who knows their stuff, but alas that does not describe me.

I am trying to write a function that takes a list of booleans, of some unknown length, and modifies each entry according to a few rules

Rule 1) If array[j] = false, then leave array[j] unchanged

Rule 2) if array[j] = true, then leave it true and turn any subsequent "trues" to "false"

My strategy is to make a function which will loop over the array, and once it finds the first true (if any) it will set the rest of the entries to false and break out of the loop. I will pass the function the size of the array and the first entry (from which I will obtain the address of the beginning of the array by de-referencing it).

The only assumptions I have to make (I think) are that
1) The array contents will be contiguous in memory
2) The memory won't be repurposed in between the creation of the array, and the calling of the function.

My function looks like this -

```
void takeFirstTrue(char size, bool list0)
{
bool* myPtr = NULL; 

for (char j = 0; j <= (size - 1); j++)
{
    myPtr = &list0 + j;

    if ( *myPtr )
    {
        for (char k = 0; k <= (size - 1); k++) { *(&list0 + k) = false;}
        *(&list0 + j) = true;
        j = size; 
    }
}
}
```

The odd thing here is that sometimes it works, and sometimes it mistakenly sets the first entry to true, regardless of the "real" value. I come from a lower level H/W background, so I'm used to thinking about register addresses and program counters and stuff like that. A lot of these higher level language features are new to me, so I'm assuming I'm violating some rule I'm unaware of.

PS - I'm sure there are nice libraries for handling this stuff. I've heard (though don't know much about) things like boost and smart pointers. Please don't recommend those, at least not just yet. I want to learn how to pull all the right levers myself.

Comment: Since you're passing `list0` by value it is not part of any array.  Is there a reason you're not passing a pointer to the actual array or, preferably since you tagged this C++, using a vector?

Comment: @RetiredNinja: `std::vector<bool>` is fraught with peril. Avoid it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja no particular reason. I tried passing a pointer initially, and when it wasn't doing what I wanted I started changing things =)

Comment: @Deduplicator `std::vector<bool>` is not without its quirks, but as long as you know that it isn't that bad.  In the cases where the quirks are just too quirky there's always `std::vector<char>` or `boost::dynamic_bitset`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bool list0` is a single boolean. It is not a list. When you write `&list0 + j` you cause undefined behaviour.

Do this instead:

```
void takeFirstTrue(int size, bool list[])
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
    {
        bool *myPtr = &list[j];
        // ..
        list[k] = false;
```

I used `int` instead of `char` as you are less likely to overflow an int than a char. It's actually better to use `size_t`, as long as you are familiar with how unsigned types work in C++.

Comment: &list0 should still be the starting address though, no? and then I should be able to access successive entries by adding the increasing value of j and then seeing what's at that address? (I read somewhere a boolean is 1 byte, so I'm just adding j, not a higher multiple of j)

Comment: No. **list0 is not a list**. It is just a single bool. It's not the starting address of anything except for a single bool.

Comment: I never argued that list0 was anything other than a single bool. What I am asking, is, assuming I have my array of booleans, why can't I pass this function the first entry and then obtain the address with the & operator?

Comment: Because a single bool does not have any other bools after it. It's not an array of booleans. It doesn't matter whether or not this is a copy of a boolean that was in an array.

Comment: It sounds like you might be thinking of something like `void takeFirstTrue(int size, bool &list)`

Comment: in your original code, list0 is passed by value. This means that as part of calling the function stack space is allocated and a copy of the value of list0 is assigned to it. So you are taking the address of a variable on the stack thinking it is your variable from the call site. In Matt's solution the stack space is filled with a copy of the pointer to the array passed at the call site (list[] equals *list (sort of)).

Answer (score 1):

You mention your hardware background. From this I suspect that your confusion comes from the difference between assembly and C subroutine calling conventions.

In assembly you use registers to pass parameters to functions. Here is does not matter whether you are at the call site or in the calling function, a register hold its value regardless where you are.

In higher level languages this does not hold true. Parameters are typically passed by value. This means that inside the function you only have a copy of the variable, not the variable itself. In order to get access to the actual variable you need to pass a pointer as a parameter (of which a copy is created) which you then dereference to get the variable at the call sites memory location.

I suggest to write some simple programs and use gcc with the -E switch to create assembly listings. You'll get some insight what the compiler does and present you with something you are probably more familiar with.

Good Luck

Comment: So in Matt's example above, he's passing in an array. That must be an example of pass by reference? If it were pass by value it couldn't possibly modify the original array right?

Comment: No, he is passing a pointer to the array. Remember that "bool list[]" is equivalent to "bool *list". This pointer is passed "by value". In C++ you pass by reference by using the & operator (for example int& var) in the function signature.